# Cloud Foundry for SaaS

Tags: service, cloud-foundry, restart, saas

I am implementing a service broker for my SaaS application on Cloud Foundry.

On create-service of my SaaS application, I create instance of another service (Say service-A) also ie. a new service instance of another service (service-A) is also created for every tenant which on-boards my application.

The details of the newly created service instance (service-A) is passed to my service-broker via environment variable.

To be able to process this newly injected environment variable, the service-broker need to be restaged/restarted.

This means a down-time for the service-broker for every new on-boarding customer.

I have following questions:
1) How these kind on use-cases are handled in Cloud Foundry?
2) Why Cloud Foundry chose to use environment variables to pass the info required to use a service? It seems limiting, as it requires application restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first guess, your service could be some kind of API provided to a customer. This API must store the data it is sent in some database (e.g. MongoDb or Mysql). So MongoDb or Mysql would be what you call Service-A.

Since you want the performance of the API endpoints for your customers to be independent of each other, you are provisioning dedicated databases for each of your customers, that is for each of the service instances of your service.

You are right in that you would need to restage your service broker if you were to get the credentials to these databases from the environment of your service broker. Or at least you would have to re-read the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. Yet there is another solution:

Use the CC-API to create the services, and bind them to whatever app you like. Then use again the CC-API to query the bindings of this app. This will include the credentials. Here is the link to the API docs on this endpoint:

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/247/apps/list_all_service_bindings_for_the_app.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is using CC-API common? Are there any down sides from your experience?

Comment: I believe this is a quite common scenario. Also the cf cli uses the CC-API behind the scenes. The difficult thing about this API is that it uses oauth for authentication. But I guess there are libraries that could do this for you.

Comment: There are CloudController API libraries, notably the Java one: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client

Comment: @user152468 : Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: @EngineerBetter Thanks for API

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not using services in the 'correct' manner. It's very hard to tell without more detail of your use case. For instance, why does your broker need to have this additional service attached?

To answer your questions:

1) Not like this. You're using service bindings to represent data, rather than using them as backing services. Many service brokers (I've written quite a few) need to dynamically provision things like Cassandra clusters, but they keep some state about which Cassandra clusters belong to which CF service in a data store of their own. The broker does not bind to each thing it is responsible for creating.

2) Because 12 [Factor applications should treat backing services as attached, static resources](https://12factor.net/backing-services). It is not normal to say add a new MySQL database to a running application.

Comment: In the example of Cassandra, you mean that services by default will have some clusters reserved for them? What happens, if the service broker needs one more cluster? Shouldn't clusters be reserved as and when broker needs them?

Comment: That's a very specific question that depends on the Service Broker implementation. More sophisticated brokers provision new VMs via BOSH or some other means.

I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve, or why you need to provision an additional service instance to your broker, in addition to binding your own service to their app.

Comment: My use case is something similar to one mentioned by user152468 in other answer. Do you see any flaws with this kind of use cases?

Comment: I still don't understand why the _user's_ app needs to have a data service bound to it; that sounds like something your broker should have bound to it. If a user binds to your one service, they don't expect to suddenly have two services bound to their app.

Perhaps you could 'compose' the other service. Your broker does what it needs to do, and calls the other broker, passing back any credentials apps will need to the CloudController. This makes it transparent to the user that many services are involved.

Comment: Exactly, my broker is creating and binding to another service for every customer which creates instance of my service. Now my broker needs to restage/restart to get credentials of this service, which is the problem.